# Find simple polygons enclosing strict subset of points on a plane

Tags: algorithms, computational-geometry

Given some set of black points and white points on a plane, what is a good way to find simple polygons that enclose all the black points and none of the white points?

I'm not sure what exactly I mean by "simple", but it is important as we don't want a little polygon around each black point if, for example, we could have grouped all the black points into one convex polygon without catching white points.

For lack of better ideas I'm considering merging adjacent triangles (where appropriate) from a Delaunay triangulation of the plane.

Is there any similar named problem in literature?

Answer (score 1):

For red and blue points in general position,
the paper below finds conditions where one can form a polygon connecting
all the blue points and excluding all the red points.

> Fulek, Radoslav, Balázs Keszegh, Filip Morić, and Igor Uljarević. "On polygons excluding point sets." *Graphs and Combinatorics* 29, no. 6 (2013): 1741-1753.
>   ([arXiv abs](https://arxiv.org/abs/0912.2914).)

---

[image: BluePolygonization]

          

<sup>Figure 1: (a) A blue polygonization excluding all the red points.</sup>

---

Perhaps more directly relevant to your case, they prove (Theorem 8)
that
there exists a simple polygon with at most $3\lceil n/2 \rceil$ vertices that separates the blue from the red points.
So it can be accomplished with just one polygon.

**Added**.
In response to the OP's comments, this how I would phrase the question: Find a simple polygon $P$ enclosing blue points and excluding red points, and minimize the number of reflex vertices of $P$. This is a well-defined optimization problem, and has at least one solution (by Theorem 8). Another version would seek to minimize the perimeter of $P$, which (roughly) varies with the number of reflex vertices. This latter optimization question is known to be NP-hard:

> Eades, Peter, and David Rappaport. "The complexity of computing minimum separating polygons." *Pattern Recognition Letters* 14.9 (1993): 715-718.
>   ([Journal link](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0167865593901409).)

Likely any
reasonable formulation is NP-hard. So you should look for approximation algorithms, e.g.:

> Reinbacher, Iris, Marc Benkert, Marc Van Kreveld, Joseph SB Mitchell, Jack Snoeyink, and Alexander Wolff. "Delineating boundaries for imprecise regions." *Algorithmica* 50, no. 3 (2008): 386-414.
>   ([Journal link](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs00453-007-9042-5?LI=true).)
>   
>  
>   [image: Snippet]

---

Comment: Thanks. I had seen this paper, but here the polygon's *perimeter* connects the blue points; I just need the polygon to *enclose* them.

Comment: As you say, theorem 8 is more directly relevant, but it essentially creates very thin tunnels to reach each blue point at all costs. I think a more reasonable objective function (than number of polygons) is the total curvature (angle swept) around all polygons used. This makes a thin tunnel as costly as a separate convex polygon.

Comment: @Museful: Perhaps if you implement Theorem 8 it will actually perform well. In any case, your problem is not well-defined enough to admit a definitive answer.

Comment: Imagine we have 1000 blue points scattered within a square, and 1000 red points outside the square. These points can be separated by one convex polygon (360 degrees of total absolute curvature). But theorem 8 (as I understand it) would yield a 1500-vertex polygon with extremely sharp angles all over the place, and a total absolute curvature the equivalent of 500 convex polygons instead of 1.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. Minimizing total curvature (sum of |pi-theta| where theta is internal angle of each vertex) would presumably be better, but as soon as I make the objective function so specific, I feel that I am potentially excluding good/simple approaches that may optimize slightly different objective functions.